# How to remove the flooring system from Mercedes 614d minibus

Tags: mercedes-benz

I'm looking to convert a Mercedes 614d  minibus into a catering truck. Can the floor system,rails which keep the seats in place, be removed as would like to make the floor lower. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a friend that wanted to convert her minibus (Renault Master) into a camper and her requirements where to remove the false floor in order to free up around two/three feet of headspace along three quarters of the length of the minibus. I helped her to remove the floor and it wasn't too difficult. I'm a fairly amateur diy enthusiast. I'm presuming you're hesitant and asking as there are no obvious bolts etc to remove the floor. My friends false floor was moulded into the walls with a steel frame on the underside. It took me around four hours to remove it with a 230mm electric angle grinder. It worked well, just take your time and I wouldn't even try to tackle it with a 115mm angle grinder - it'd take forever and a day and the discs probably won't go all the way through. I used the grinder through the floor as well as the frame so it was an EXTREMELY dusty job. Be sure to use a good quality dust mask - good one costs £15. Keep all windows and doors open and have a spotter for stray sparks when working near the seats/soft furnishings. I went through about 5 discs. Just be careful of any wiring and you'll be fine. If I can do it (novice d.i.y'er) then anyone can! Hope this is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer,reckon I might be able to give it a go